# Automating publishing WCF services and updating its references

Tags: c#, wcf, publish, auto-update

Even this is not a critical issue, I am having some serious malfunctionings because of some user errors, so I need to find a solution to this problem.

I have a layered service based application. The least degree of layers is 2 in my architecture. So when I make a change that requires reference updating on clients, I need to publish first layer then update reference of first layer on second layer, then publish second layer after that update reference of second layer on client application. If this was all I had to do I believe I could survive, but I have 5 different services like this and everyone of them has `implementation` and `production` environments to publish. And I easily get confused with these steps.

When I did a quick research I found thinds like `built script`. But since in my case there is update service reference operation too, I'm not sure if it would work. So I am asking for a tool, or an approach to publish services and update references in some certain orders.

Comment: What product are you using for source control?

Comment: I am using visual studio with Team Foundation Server

Comment: Not a solution, but a tip: Don't change parameters on methods that are in production use. If you are worried that you might need to expand on a method later use an object as a parameter, because they can easily be expanded without the need to update if you do not require them. If you would still need to change the arguments/parameters of a method make a new method with same name and a number indicating there is a new version. eg: `MyMethod(int Id)` --> `MyMethod2(int Id, DataContractType queryObject)`. This is quite common in web services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same problem with updating service references for a dozen of services.

If your service and client projects can share a common service contract DLL (have a project reference to project with service types), you can use channel factory for creating clients. In this case you will not need service references at all.

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/MathService/Ep1");
ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
IMath wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
double s = wcfClient1.Add(3, 39);
((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();
```

You can read more there http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/creating-a-wcf-service-proxy-with-channelfactory/

Comment: Thanks foy your answer, I liked it actually. But there is one thing preoccupying my mind, and that is if my client application gets reverse engineered, then my service dll could be resolved and my precious business logic will be exposed. Am I correct? However I can bypass through this problem using service reference only on end client, and on service layers I can use your approach. Fair enough for me :) Thanks again.

Comment: Keep your service types and interface in separate project, for example serviceName.Common.cproj. Implement your business logic in serviceName.Core.cproj and your client logic in serviceName.Client.cproj. These projects will have project reference to serviceName.Common.cproj, so your client application won't have reference to service dll with your logic